# How can I install a third-party .deb package in an arbitrary base dir?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, deb

I have a .deb which politely installs itself in /opt. For my purposes I would prefer it acted like a first-class citizen and installed itself in the regular filesystem locations.

Is there a way to do this?

This is Ubuntu 10.04.4

**update**

I have tried `--root=/`, it doesn't change the installation location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without rebuilding the Debian package--which is certainly an option if you want to create your own directory hierarchy.  The package was--presumably--built and tested based on the directory structure in /opt, and without knowing details about the package, it may not even be ABLE to be run without being in that directory.